# Efficiently convert a string of comma separated values to bytes

Tags: performance, python-3.x, encode

My `python3` program is receiving data from elsewhere as a string in the following format (the `...` means more data that I care to type out):

```
data = "0,12,145,234;1,0,0,128;2,255,255,255;...;909,100,100,100;"
```

I want to convert this to packed binary data where I disregard the `,` and `;` characters. Currently, I am doing the following:

```
splitData = data.split(';')[:-1] # ignore the last ';'
buff = []
for item in splitData:
    addr, R, G, B = item.split(',')
    addr = int(addr) # two bytes
    R    = int(R)    # one byte
    G    = int(G)    # one byte
    B    = int(B)    # one byte
    packed = struct.pack('HBBB', addr, R, G, B)
    buff.append(packed)
dataBytes = b''.join(buff)
```

For my example data above, this process gives me the following:

```
dataBytes = b'\x00\x00\x0c\x91\xea\x01\x00\x00\x00\x80...\x8d\x03ddd'
```

which is what I want (and is about one third the size of the original string).

However, this process is taking about `0.002` seconds. I need to do this process 33 times per frame, which leads to about `0.05` seconds to compute, amounting to about 20 frames per second. I would like to speed this up, if possible.

Is there a way to convert from the string data to byte data which is faster than the method above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using itertools, doing a replace then splitting, mapping to int and finally zipping in fours is about 25 percent faster:

```
 In [82]: data = "0,12,145,234;1,0,0,128;2,255,255,255;909,100,100,100;" * 1000
 In [83]: from itertools import  imap, izip
 [84]: %%timeit  
splitData = data.split(';')[:-1] # ignore the last ';'
buff = []
for item in splitData:
    addr, R, G, B = item.split(',')
    addr = int(addr) # two bytes
    R    = int(R)    # one byte
    G    = int(G)    # one byte
    B    = int(B)    # one byte
    packed = struct.pack('HBBB', addr, R, G, B)
    buff.append(packed)
dataBytes = b''.join(buff)
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.61 ms per loop

In [85]: %%timeit     
mapped = imap(int, data[:-1].replace(";", ",").split(","))
b"".join([struct.pack('HBBB', *sub) for sub in izip(mapped, mapped, mapped, mapped)])
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 6.27 ms per loop
```

Using python3, just use map and zip:

```
In [4]: %%timeit
mapped = map(int, data[:-1].replace(";", ",").split(","))
b"".join([struct.pack('HBBB', *sub) for sub in zip(mapped, mapped, mapped, mapped)])
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.61 ms per loop

In [5]: %%timeit        
splitData = data.split(';')[:-1] # ignore the last ';'
buff = []                                                                  for item in splitData:
    addr, R, G, B = item.split(',')
    addr = int(addr) # two bytes
    R    = int(R)    # one byte
    G    = int(G)    # one byte
    B    = int(B)    # one byte
    packed = struct.pack('HBBB', addr, R, G, B)
    buff.append(packed)
dataBytes = b''.join(buff)
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.89 ms per loop
```

Comment: Super smart! Taking off my answer (+1)

Comment: This is faster! I'm getting `0.00156` seconds whereas before I was getting `0.00202` seconds.